# Adding text to another window using window.open() JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xhtml

I have a button that opens a new window when clicked. How would I add some text to the new window, I am opening. As I am using an xhtml document I'm finding it hard to find anything that works.

```
function prizes() 
{
var mywindow = window.open("prizes.xhtml","MsgWindow","width=300,height=300,top=200,left=500");

}
```

Also would it be possible to add text to this window depending on a value that is in another element for example if an elements value = 10 then display "you scored 10" etc..

Comment: Are you sure you're not simply looking for `alert`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tryed something like

```
mywindow.document.getElementById("someid").innerHTML = "bla bla";
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, I dont think innerHTML works with XHTML

Comment: Have you tried DOM property .textContent instead of innerHTML?

Comment: ...also make sure your XHTML document has loaded before trying alter it

Answer (score 0):

In the child window you can use JS to talk to the parent window using `window.opener`.

`alert(window.opener.myValue)`;

Of course you can inject this value into the DOM using already established techniques.

Comment: So using this method how would I get the page to output some text?